# Joomla TinyMCE deletes empty span

Tags: joomla, tinymce

I want to use following tag

```
<h4><span class="icon-phone"></span></h4>
```

but TinyMCE from Joomla always deletes it, when i save it.

I find the solution that i have to add span[*] to "Extended Valid Elements" in Options from TinyMCE in PluginManager. but it doesn't work. It always delete it again and again. I searched here for a while and found some articles which was similar to my problem but doesn't solve it.

I use Joomla Version 3.3.6 and the plugin is 4.1.2.

Hope somebody can help.

Best Regards,
Dennis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TinyMCE, my most hated editor ever.

I've had the same problem multiple times and I believe it's because the editor expects content within the element. So try the following:

```
<h4><span class="icon-phone">&nbsp;</span></h4>
```

`&nbsp;` is simply a non breaking space

Comment: Oh yeah, it's also my first impression of it. Until now I tried the simplest html-Code like you see and there i have already a problem.

Ok, thank you very much for your Solution, it does work!

But meanwhile i found another solution / Workaround. I tried to use the JCE Editor. With that Editor i have no problem yet.
But however, ita's already good to know how to solve it with TinyMCE.

Comment: That's why a lot of users install a different editor. The most popular one being [JCE Editor](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/). Anyway, did my solution fix the issue?

Comment: Ah glad you got it fixed. Please either mark my answer as accepted by clicking the "tick" icon, or add your own answer to people know it has been solved ;)

Comment: In future, please don't forget to ask your question at the dedicated [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) site :)

Comment: Ok, i marked it as resolved.
Oh, ok, sorry i don't know that a site only for question about Joomla does exist. In future is ask my questions there ;)!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

go to: Joomla! administration - Extensions - Plugins - edit Editor - TinyMCE

Set the following parameter:
**Extended Valid Elements**: `span[class|style]`

This works for me in Joomla! 3.5 (plugin version 4.3.3)